# What are the requirments for ISupportInitialize code to be serialized in InitializeComponent? .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I need to add some code to the EndInit method of a PictureBox control, but unfortunately it's private and, from what I can gather, I can't shadow it and call base - at least not in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

What I can do is to add a dummy property to my picture box class. The type of the dummy property is simply a class that just implements `ISupportInitialize`. However, that doesn't work, I need the dummy class to inherit from Control.

Is that the minimum requirement?

Comment: Are you making a control that inherits `PictureBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you need to make a proeprty that holds a dummy class implementing `ISupportInitialize`.

Then, expose the property like this:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]  //Hide from IntelliSense (outside your solution)
[Browsable(false)]   //Hide from Properties window
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public MyDummyClass Initializer { get; private set; }
```

Specifying `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` will cause the designer to set the proeprties of the object instead of the object itself, and will also cause it to  call `BeginInit` / `EndInit`.

Obviously, you should instantiate the class in your constructor.

Comment: I've added the DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content attribute but I still need my dummy class to derive from control. I'll try the code in c# and see if I get a different result.

Comment: I tested it in C# and the dummy class needed to inherit from Control. This seems a bit heavy handed but its possible that I don't need to inherit from Control but instead implement one of the many interfaces that control implements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all you need to inherit is `Component`.

Comment: I've got it down to IComponent, that'll do for me. Cheers for the pointer.

Comment: Just to add, the DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content attribute is not needed unless you make the dummy property ReadOnly.

Comment: Check the designer code; it should be more efficient that way.